# Prove that after some finite steps $(m,n)$ will ultimately reduce to $(0,1)$, or $(1,1)$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was doing a gcd sum, and notice this:

You are given 2 numbers say  $m$ and $n$, with $gcd(m,n)=1$. We perform series of steps. The rules are :

If $m>n$ then

- If $m>2n$ , then in the next step write $(m,n)$ as $(m-2n,n)$
- If $n<m<2n$, then in the next step write $(m,n)$ as $(m,2n-m)$

Similarly for $n$.

Prove that after some finite steps $(m,n)$ will ultimately reduce to $(0,1)$, or $(1,1)$.

Note: Every pair is unordered.

Here's an example: $(100,23)\rightarrow (54,23) \rightarrow (8,23)\rightarrow (8,7)\rightarrow (6,7) \rightarrow(6,5)\rightarrow (4,5) \rightarrow(5,4)\rightarrow (4,3)\rightarrow (2,3)$

Comment: Induction looks likely.  Use $m+n$ as the induction index.  Note that the parity of $m+n$ is preserved by your operation and that determines which of $(1,0),(1,1)$ you wind up at.

Comment: @Raheel trying to create something like the Collatz chains ?

Comment: Even without the initial condition that $gcd=1$, doesn't your procedure always reach one of the fixed points $(gcd,gcd)$ or $(gcd,0)?$